# WSO2 CEP agent broker (KPI Analyzer) sample is not working with aggragate queries

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, broker

I am working on Apache WSO2 CEP and I am trying to do some scenarios that fits my requirements.

First I execute the sample that is explained in this link [KPI Analyzer](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/CEP210/KPI+Analyzer) and I succced and see the result correctly. After that, I wanted to change the bucket in that sample a little bit from this

```
from phoneRetailStream[totalPrice>2500 and quantity>3]
insert into highPurchaseStream
buyer, brand, quantity, totalPrice;
```

to this

```
from phoneRetailStream#window.length(5)
insert into highPurchaseStream
sum(quantity) as quantitySum, sum(totalPrice) as totalpriceSum
group by  brand;
```

and changed the tuple mappings accordingly. But this configuration always gives me the error

```
 [java] Wrongly formatted event sent for carbon.super
 [java] org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting org.wso2.high.purchase.buyers.new:1.6.0 of event bundle with events 4
 [java]     at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:126)
 [java]     at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:88)
 [java]     at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:72)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
 [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 [java]     at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toObjectArray(ThriftEventConverter.java:49)
 [java]     at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:116)
 [java]     ... 8 more
```

I could not use aggration functions (sum, avg etc.) of siddhi language in these samples other than jmsbroker. What may be wrong with this scenario?

@Mohanadarshan

This is the last version of my bucket xml file

```
<bucket name="KPIAnalyzer" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/cep">
    <description>
Notifies when a user purchases more then 3 phones for the total price higher than $2500.
    </description>
    <engineProviderConfiguration engineProvider="SiddhiCEPRuntime">
        <property name="siddhi.persistence.snapshot.time.interval.minutes">0</property>
        <property name="siddhi.enable.distributed.processing">false</property>
    </engineProviderConfiguration>
    <input topic="org.wso2.phone.retail.store/1.2.0" brokerName="localAgentBroker">
        <tupleMapping stream="phoneRetailStream" queryEventType="Tuple">
            <property name="brand" inputName="brand" inputDataType="payloadData"
                      type="java.lang.String"/>
            <property name="quantity" inputName="quantity" inputDataType="payloadData"
                      type="java.lang.Integer"/>
            <property name="totalPrice" inputName="total" inputDataType="payloadData"
                      type="java.lang.Integer"/>
            <property name="buyer" inputName="buyer" inputDataType="payloadData"
                      type="java.lang.String"/>
        </tupleMapping>
    </input>
    <query name="KPIQuery">
        <expression>
from phoneRetailStream#window.length(5)
insert into highPurchaseStream
sum(quantity) as quantitySum, sum(totalPrice) as totalpriceSum
group by  brand;
        </expression>
        <output topic="org.wso2.high.purchase.buyers.new/1.6.0" brokerName="externalAgentBroker">
            <tupleMapping>
                <metaData>
                </metaData>
                <correlationData/>
                <payloadData>
                    <property name="quantity" valueOf="quantitySum" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
                    <property name="purchasePrice" valueOf="totalpriceSum" type="java.lang.Integer"/>
                </payloadData>
            </tupleMapping>
        </output>
    </query>
</bucket>
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked your siddhi query, it is working properly with siddhi engine and there is no any issue with the query...

I have checked with the KPI analyser example, it is also working without any issue for your query... Please make sure whether you have proper configurations for output tuple mappings..

Again I need to mention, there are some issue with the "bucket editable UI". Please verify the bucket xml file which in the /repository/deployment/server/cepbuckets/ is correct... (some times when deleting a property, it will not delete properly)

**Change**

```
<property name="quantity" valueOf="quantitySum" type="java.lang.Long"/>
<property name="purchasePrice" valueOf="totalpriceSum" type="java.lang.Long"/>
```

Thanks,

Mohan

Comment: Hi @Mohanadarshan, I edit my question and add bucket xml file, can you look at the output tuple mappings? What could be wrong. Again, I must say this example works as it is, but it is giving error when we had changed the output query as containing "sum", "avg" etc.

Comment: Hi,I have deployed your bucket xml... It is deployed in the CEP server without any issue and working perfectly... I can see the output in the Test Server... see the output [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B056dKd2JQGJOFhZX0ZpUUpXejg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi @Mohanadarshan, I think you give your testAgentServer to input agentbroker, I am saying that because in your screenshot, you have 20 events and according to my query, for example, second "Samsung" event must have value greater than 4. Other than that in payload data only two value must be decleared(quantitySum, and totalpricesum). The screenshot seems only show your input from PhoneRetailAgent. Can you consider this and check that?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late... I'm able to reproduce the exception that you mention above... I'm investigating further to identify the issue... I'll get back to with more information ASAP... Thanks..

Comment: Thank you @Mohanadarshan, I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: Hi, I have checked your query it is working... If you tried that with some other external broker like emailbroker... then it is working... I thing the issue is with the AgentTestServer... I'm looking in to that further and give you feedback on this...

Comment: Yes @Mohanadarshan, I tried with another broker too. What could be wrong with the AgentTestServer?

Comment: Hi, we have found the issue after verifying with our team-lead... The issue is in the output tuple mapping.. If you get a sum of a property, then the type of that sum property is long.. change the output mapping as I edited in my answer... Thanks... :)